# How to count a distance when travelling through several points on the same line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, time, distance

Travel time is not counting the shortest way but the travel on the same railway line through multiple stations.

```
public double TravelTimeOnSameLine(IStation from, IStation to, int speed)
{
    //check values
    if (from == to || from == null || to == null || speed <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    var commonLines = from.Lines.Intersect(to.Lines);
    if (!commonLines.Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    var line = commonLines.First();
    var distance = 0.0;

    //how to fimd the path?
    var path = new List<IStation>();
    var current = from;
    path.Add(from);


    while (current != to)
    {
        current = line.Next(current);
        path.Add(current);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
    {
        IStation firstStation = null;
        IStation secondStation = null;

        firstStation = from;
        secondStation = to;

        //calcul de distance entre deux points;
        var distanceBetween1and2 = GetDistancebtween(firstStation.X, firstStation.Y, secondStation.X, secondStation.Y);
        distance = distance + distanceBetween1and2;

    }

    var travelTime = distance / speed;
    return travelTime;
}
```

I am trying to pass a last unit tests (code lines 12-16 where different speed is used for same distance and last line adding multiple station on the same train line that are not graphically on the same horizontal or vertical line) and I am missing the calculation when I count a travel time through multiple stations.

```
public void T2_travel_time_on_simple_stations()
{
    ICity c = CityFactory.CreateCity("Paris");

    IStation s = c.AddStation("Opera", 0, 0);
    IStation s1 = c.AddStation("Chatelet", 10, 0);

    ILine l = c.AddLine("RER A");
    l.AddBefore(s);
    l.AddBefore(s1);

    c.TravelTimeOnSameLine( s, s1, 1).Should().Be(10.0);
    c.TravelTimeOnSameLine( s, s1, 10).Should().Be(1.0);
    c.TravelTimeOnSameLine( s, s1, 100).Should().Be(0.1);
    c.TravelTimeOnSameLine( s, s1, 20).Should().Be(0.5);
    c.TravelTimeOnSameLine( s, s1, 20).Should().Be(c.TravelTimeOnSameLine( s1, s, 20));
}
[Test]
public void T3_travel_time_on_more_stations()
{
    ICity city = CityFactory.CreateCity("Paris");

    IStation a = city.AddStation("A", 0, 0);
    IStation b = city.AddStation("B", 0, 10);
    IStation c = city.AddStation("C", 10, 10);
    IStation d = city.AddStation("D", 10, 0);

    ILine l1 = city.AddLine("ligne 1");

    l1.AddBefore(a);
    l1.AddBefore(b);
    l1.AddBefore(c);
    l1.AddBefore(d);

    city.TravelTimeOnSameLine( a, d, 1).Should().Be(30.0);
}
```

Error message Expected valu to be 10.0, but found 20.0.

Comment: So you expect 30.0... I assume you're failing with a value of 10.0? How is `TravelTimeOnSameLine` suppose to know that it needs calculate the distance from `a` to `d` **via** `b` and `c`?

Comment: I am failing exactly like this. First errot in cal of distances (A&B, B&C, C&D). I am using the function Next to find a station TO. ```public IStation Next(IStation s)
{
    if (!_stations.Contains(s))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    var index = _stations.IndexOf(s);
    var isLast = index == _stations.Count -1;
    if (isLast)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return _stations[index + 1];
}  ``` and then I try to calculate distance between 2 stations and then do the sum of all distance (for the case we travel through more then 2 stations) and duration.

Comment: Please post `GetDistancebtween`.

Comment: private double GetDistancebtween(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.Pow((y1 - y2), 2)); ;
        }

Comment: I'm a little hesitant to post this without seeing the rest of the code... It probably won't help... But here's what I'm seeing... you're using an Intersect method to get lines common to both `a` and `d`, however there are no lines common to them, maybe that's okay... Also, in your `foreach`, you're returning a value on the first iteration, so it'll never actually loop though more than one `IStation`. You probably want something more like `distance += GetDistancebtween(x1: from.X, y1: from.Y, x2: finalStation.X, y2: finalStation.Y);` and fix the rest of the code.

Comment: ...and many would prefer to see your distance formula written as `x2 - x1` and `y2 - y1`

Comment: agree, it is due to my other functions. Thanks for the hint, still though in the magic circle that I can't find my way out.